# Serializing socket

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I tried serializing socket but it didn't work.
what is the proper way ?

```
public class MySocket implements Serializable
{
    private Socket socket;

    public MySocket(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;

    }
    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }
    public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }
```

}

Comment: Ehm... why do you want to serialize a Socket?

Comment: Its possible that we may want to save the Socket object on memcached. Its a valid scenario.

Answer (score 9):

By design `Socket` instances are not serializable - you cannot save them or transmit them over a network, that wouldn't make any sense. Depending on what you're trying to do, you need to establish a new socket each time you need one rather than saving it to disk etc.

Answer (score 1):

Socket basically is a file descriptor on the system level, similar to a file. It's just an integer. It can be serialized but it doesn't make sense to do so. When a socket is closed, the file descriptor no long makes sense. It also doesn't make sense if you use it on another machine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, In socket programming when you say serialize that means the object should be "serializable" not the socket it self.

```
inSomeclass's method {
     ...
     ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     out.writeObject(new MyClass());
     out.flush();
     ...
}

class MyClass implements Serializable {
     // some sort of variables and objects, whatever ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would not work since a member variable "socket" is not serializable.

Do you want to serialize something over a socket? In that case the class that has data should be serialized not the one that is handling sockets.